# java.sql.SQLException: An undefined column name was detected. (Hibernate)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, exception, db2

I have the following method that is giving me a an exception.

```
private double doFullCalculation(Iterable<OfferToCatalog> startOfferCatalogs, Iterable<OfferToCatalog> endOfferCatalogs){
        double fullWeeksSales=0d;
        int startWeeks=0;
        int startIteration =0;
        for(OfferToCatalog startOfferToCatalog: startOfferCatalogs){
            List<OfferWeeks> startOfferWeeks = offerWeeksRepository.getWeeksForCatalogNumber(startOfferToCatalog.getOfferToCatalogKey().getBusinessUnitNumber()+""+startOfferToCatalog.getOfferToCatalogKey().getCatalogNumber()+""+startOfferToCatalog.getOfferToCatalogKey().getCatalogVersion());
            startIteration++;
            if(startIteration==1){
                startWeeks=startOfferWeeks.size();
            }
         fullWeeksSales += addStartWeeks(startWeeks, startOfferWeeks);   
        }
        for(OfferToCatalog endOfferToCatalog: endOfferCatalogs){    
            List<OfferWeeks> endOfferWeeks = offerWeeksRepository.getWeeksForCatalogNumber(endOfferToCatalog.getOfferToCatalogKey().getBusinessUnitNumber()+""+endOfferToCatalog.getOfferToCatalogKey().getCatalogNumber()+""+endOfferToCatalog.getOfferToCatalogKey().getCatalogVersion());
            fullWeeksSales += addEndWeeks(startWeeks, endOfferWeeks);   
        }
        return fullWeeksSales;   
    }
```

I only seem to get an error in the second for loop (the portion that gets endOfferWeeks). It's calling the exact same method as in the startOfferWeeks for loop, but I get the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: An undefined column name was detected.
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:408)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:380)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDServerRow.findField(JDServerRow.java:482)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCResultSet.findColumn(AS400JDBCResultSet.java:557)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCResultSet.getBigDecimal(AS400JDBCResultSet.java:2239)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_com_ibm_as400_access_AS400JDBCResultSet.getBigDecimal(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.DecimalTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(DecimalTypeDescriptor.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2283)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1527)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1455)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:611)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1842)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:246)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:96)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:337)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy131.getWeeksForCatalogNumber(Unknown Source)
    at com.oriental.oft.service.impl.OfferServiceImpl.doFullCalculation(OfferServiceImpl.java:340)
    at com.oriental.oft.service.impl.OfferServiceImpl.processFTF(OfferServiceImpl.java:297)
    at com.oriental.oft.service.impl.OfferServiceImpl.getForecastJSON(OfferServiceImpl.java:588)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
    at $Proxy133.getForecastJSON(Unknown Source)
    at com.oriental.oft.web.controller.AuthenticationController.getForecastJSON(AuthenticationController.java:76)
    at com.oriental.oft.web.controller.AuthenticationController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$7a6d41ea.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.oriental.oft.web.controller.AuthenticationController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$803ec396.getForecastJSON(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3592)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2202)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2108)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1432)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
>
```

I've looked at other posts for this issue, but this one seems to be different because the query seems to run fine the first time(s) it's executed. It's only in the second section of this method that I'm having an issue. I've looked to see what's being passed in as a parameter, and the query runs fine when I use DB Visualizer.

This is what my repository looks like if that's useful.

```
public interface OfferWeeksRepository extends CrudRepository<OfferWeeks, String>, 
        JpaRepository<OfferWeeks, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<OfferWeeks> {
     @Query(value="select a.FCLYERWK, cast(sum(a.RMSALES) as decimal(18,5)) " +
            "from DWALCTNFL as a " +
            "inner join ( " +
            "select b.ITMNBR, b.CATPFX " +
            "from OECATPAG b " +
            "where (b.PAGNBR >= 0 and b.PAGNBR < 600) AND " +
            "(b.PHOSIZ+b.TXTSIZ+b.WHTSPCSIZ) > 0 AND " + 
            "Rtrim(CAST(b.BUSUNTNBR as varchar(5)))||Rtrim(b.CATNBR)||Rtrim(b.CATVER)  = :catalogNumber " +
            "group by b.itmnbr, b.catpfx ) as c " +
            "on (a.ITMNBR=c.ITMNBR and a.ITMPFX=c.CATPFX) " +
            "where trim(a.ITMCATNBR) = :catalogNumber " +
            "group by a.FCLYERWK " +
            "order by a.FCLYERWK ", nativeQuery=true)
     List<OfferWeeks> getWeeksForCatalogNumber(@Param("catalogNumber") String catalogNumber);
}
```

What I expect to be getting from the query is this:

```
201344  239.70000
201345  6045.34500
201346  8885.38200
201347  19087.47600
201348  18076.79600
201349  22518.06900
201350  24897.04300
201351  21699.63600
201352  12532.93400
201401  13964.03500
201402  10197.32900
201403  7687.81300
201404  3980.19600
201405  4828.38000
201406  3592.61600
201407  2069.02900
201408  1612.69500
201409  3280.60700
201410  77.40000
201411  25.65700
201412  847.53000
201413  594.59100
201414  391.50000
201415  2292.53200
201416  0.00000
```

Comment: What is the value of `:catalogNumber` when it fails?

Comment: Have you looked at the messages in the job log of your connection  session on the IBM i server?  What release & TR# of IBM i is on the server?

Comment: When it fails, :catalogNumber is "1202312A". A working :catalogNumber is "1202830B"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out what the issue was. On the "pass" through the method where it failed, that was the only time the query returned data. Since the 2nd column was a summation of the data, it wasn't returning a named column without me declaring it as such.

My entity mapping was looking for a named column for the second column, but since it wasn't named in the result set my program didn't know what to do with the data.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OECATPAG")
public class OfferWeeks implements Serializable{
    String week;
    BigDecimal sales;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "FCLYERWK", columnDefinition = "varchar2(40)")
    public String getWeek() {
        return week;
    }

    public void setWeek(String week) {
        this.week = week;
    }

    @Column(name = "RMSALES", columnDefinition = "decimal(18,9)")
    public BigDecimal getSales() {
        return sales;
    }

    public void setSales(BigDecimal sales) {
        this.sales = sales;
    }

}
```